# Copy file, overwrite if newer

Tags: c#, .net

In C#.NET, How to copy a file to another location, overwriting the existing file if the source file is newer than the existing file (have a later "Modified date"), and doing noting if the source file is older?

Comment: is this windows or web approach??

Comment: You might find this easier with a batch file, I think the xcopy command makes this simple

Comment: I know your question was already answered already. I felt inclined to add my tested source to the thread that answered my initial Q. Enjoy.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You can use the [`FileInfo` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.aspx)   and it's properties and methods:

```
FileInfo file = new FileInfo(path);
string destDir = @"C:\SomeDirectory";
FileInfo destFile = new FileInfo(Path.Combine(destDir, file.Name));
if (destFile.Exists)
{
    if (file.LastWriteTime > destFile.LastWriteTime)
    { 
        // now you can safely overwrite it
        file.CopyTo(destFile.FullName, true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10):

You can use the FileInfo class:

```
FileInfo infoOld = new FileInfo("C:\\old.txt");
FileInfo infoNew = new FileInfo("C:\\new.txt");

if (infoNew.LastWriteTime > infoOld.LastWriteTime)
{
    File.Copy(source path,destination path, true) ;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is my take on the answer: Copies not moves folder contents. If the target does not exist the code is clearer to read. Technically, creating a fileinfo for a non existent file will have a LastWriteTime of DateTime.Min so it **would** copy but falls a little short on  readability. I hope this tested code helps someone.

**EDIT: I have updated my source to be much more flexable. Because it was based on this thread I have posted the update here. When using masks subdirs are not created *if* the subfolder does not contain matched files. Certainly a more robust error handler is in your future. :)

```
public void CopyFolderContents(string sourceFolder, string destinationFolder)
{
    CopyFolderContents(sourceFolder, destinationFolder, "*.*", false, false);
}

public void CopyFolderContents(string sourceFolder, string destinationFolder, string mask)
{
    CopyFolderContents(sourceFolder, destinationFolder, mask, false, false);
}

public void CopyFolderContents(string sourceFolder, string destinationFolder, string mask, Boolean createFolders, Boolean recurseFolders)
{
    try
    {
        if (!sourceFolder.EndsWith(@"\")){ sourceFolder += @"\"; }
        if (!destinationFolder.EndsWith(@"\")){ destinationFolder += @"\"; }

        var exDir = sourceFolder;
        var dir = new DirectoryInfo(exDir);
        SearchOption so = (recurseFolders ? SearchOption.AllDirectories : SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);

        foreach (string sourceFile in Directory.GetFiles(dir.ToString(), mask, so))
        {
            FileInfo srcFile = new FileInfo(sourceFile);
            string srcFileName = srcFile.Name;

            // Create a destination that matches the source structure
            FileInfo destFile = new FileInfo(destinationFolder + srcFile.FullName.Replace(sourceFolder, ""));

            if (!Directory.Exists(destFile.DirectoryName ) && createFolders)
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(destFile.DirectoryName);
            }

            if (srcFile.LastWriteTime > destFile.LastWriteTime || !destFile.Exists)
            {
                File.Copy(srcFile.FullName, destFile.FullName, true);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine + ex.StackTrace);
    }
}
```

Comment: Notice this is not a recursive call. (This need to be wikified)

Comment: This works really well. I would suggest one additional improvement. Adding a checksum test if the file exists in both the source and dest so that you don't copy the file if they are identical.


public String GetChecksum(String filePath)
{
 using (var stream = new BufferedStream(File.OpenRead(filePath), 1200000))
 {
  SHA256Managed sha = new SHA256Managed();
  byte[] checksum = sha.ComputeHash(stream);
  return BitConverter.ToString(checksum).Replace("-", String.Empty);
 }
}

Comment: @ChristopherHaws, thats a great idea. I will fold that in when I get a minute. :)

Comment: If you use `Path.Combine` instead of `+`, you won't have to do all that `if sourceFolder.EndsWith` jiggery pokery.

Answer (score 0):

In a batch file, this will work:

```
XCopy "c:\my directory\source.ext" "c:\my other directory\dest.ext" /d
```

Comment: yes.. but probably trickier since we have to deal with spaces in the path, etc.

Comment: Fair enough,I think batch files allow you to put single or double quotes around a file path if it helps